Error: TypeError: null: type 'minified:BR' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
I am keep on getting this error code Error: TypeError: null: type 'minified:BR' is not a subtype of type 'List' when I try to upload my json in the firebase to my website in flutter. Here is the code I am using and I will send the Json too

available_times
(map)
friday
"None"
(string)
monday
"None"
(string)
saturday
"None"
(string)
sunday
"None"
(string)
thursday
"None"
(string)
tuesday
"None"
(string)
wednesday
"None"
(string)
bathroom_count
1
(number)
bedroom_count
1
(number)
date_created
"2024-06-10T18:57:58.513"
(string)
description
"The Seaton Apartments"
(string)
id
"San Diego, The Seaton Apartments"
(string)
image_urls
(array)
0
"https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/72c21388c066ef4464a641937fc193bb-p_e.jpg"
(string)
last_updated
"2024-06-10T18:57:58.513"
(string)
location
(map)
city
"San Diego"
(string)
latitude
32.7163
(number)
longitude
117.1477
(number)
state_code
"CA"
(string)
state_name
"California"
(string)
street_address
"1302 Frankfort St"
(string)
zip_code
92106
(number)
main_image_url
"https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/72c21388c066ef4464a641937fc193bb-p_e.jpg"
(string)
price
3150
(number)
title
"The Seaton Apartments"
(string)
userEmail
""
(string)
username
"Grace Lewis"
(string)
Database location: nam5
I am not sure what I can do to stop my from getting this error
